# Display a welcome message for 60 minutes after creating a resource

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a resource `user` with this `show` function in the controller:

```
def show(conn, _params) do
  user =
    Repo.get!(User, conn.assigns[:user_id])

  display_welcome_message = false

  conn
  |> assign(:user, user)
  |> assign(:display_welcome_message, display_welcome_message)
  |> render("show.html", conn: conn)
end
```

I want to display a welcome message in the first 60 minutes after the `user` was created. How can I set `display_welcome_message` during that time frame to true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the difference of `user.inserted_at` against `:calendar.universal_time`:

```
inserted_at = :calendar.datetime_to_gregorian_seconds(Ecto.DateTime.to_erl(user.inserted_at))
now = :calendar.datetime_to_gregorian_seconds(:calendar.universal_time)
display_welcome_message = now - inserted_at <= 3600
...
```

This will become much simpler once Ecto 2.1 is out which uses Elixir's new native DateTime struct:

```
diff = DateTime.to_unix(DateTime.utc_now) - DateTime.to_unix(user.inserted_at)
display_welcome_message = diff <= 3600
```